# Screenshot with Tcl (for window not written in Tk)

Tags: tcl, screenshot

I need to use Tcl to capture a screenshot of a given program not written with Tk (for example Firefox).

All I found is how to use `Img` to capture Tk applications.

Any idea on how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Which platform are you running on?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a useful information here (for Windows only.)

http://wiki.tcl.tk/15647

Take an example of "wish.exe" assuming that it's default title is "wish".

```
package require twapi

set pid [exec C:/Tcl/bin/wish.exe &]
set hwnd [twapi::find_windows -text "wish" -toplevel 1 -visible 1 -single]

twapi::set_focus $hwnd
twapi::send_keys {%{PRTSC}}; # type Alt+PrintScreen key
after 200; # avoid an access denied error.
set ts [clock format [clock seconds] -format "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"]
set filename "screenshotwin_$ts.bmp"
set phImg [Clipboard2Img]; # refer to the wiki page
$phImg write [file rootname $filename].png -format PNG
```

Or simply call [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html). This is better than depending on the Alt+PrintScreen key.

```
exec C:/Tcl/bin/wish.exe &
after 100
exec nircmd.exe win activate title "wish"
after 100
exec nircmd.exe savescreenshotwin "screenshotwin.png"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Won't these two programs take a screenshot of your full screen? I need to capture the window of a given program.

Comment: How do you specify the target program, window title, pid or window picker like Spy++?

Comment: ideally window title or window picker.

Comment: ideally window title or window picker.

Comment: In the above example, replace "wish" to the window title of your target app.
As to the picker, I can provide only the idea.

1. Make a small Tk window and make it draggable over the target app window.

2. Give it's position to twapi::get_window_at_location X Y.

3. You get a window handle and you do the same thing as the above script.